# Admin override form fields attributes

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm building a profile driven admin for an app I'm building. Users have some permissions on parts of a hierarchy tree (displayed as a select in the admin form), and I'ld like to display only this part of the tree in the select. I'ld like to change the `queryset` attribute of this select field.

The form has no knowledge about the request (user), So I can't et it in the __init__ of it.

I've tryed to set `form.base_fields` in `ModelAdmin.get_form()`, but I've side effects with this method: some users can see trees of other users, and have an error message, due to permission. The only way to avoid those errors is to reload the project (at web server level), which is not an option...

I've also tryed to override the `ModelAdmin.get_fields()` method, but it does not seems to be called.

Have someone an idea on how to do this ?

... I'll provide some code ...

Admin:

https://gist.github.com/frague59/f90ba63bb2548fb27e32576329159543

Forms:

https://gist.github.com/frague59/aa5236eb11982bd810f81342da8bc05d

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be looking for the [`formfield_for_foreignkey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) method. The example in the docs shows how you restrict the queryset for a field based on the user:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "car":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Car.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I'ld like to update widgets too... But I think I'll have to override the form at this point, to provide a editor version of it.

Comment: The [`formfield_overrides`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) option lets you change the widget for foreign keys, or if you might be able to set it in `formfield_for_foreignkey`. I can't offer any other advice because you haven't shown any code in your question.

Comment: It does nor work. While debugging, I can see the queryset changing, but at the end of the form initialization, another instance of the form field is attached to the new form.

Comment: I's about the `TreeNodeChoiceField`, which require a queryset at init. I've updated my `EditorPeopleAdminForm` to use the basic `ModelChoiceField` for `hierarchy`, which works. I's a bit complicated... no ?

Comment: The Django admin is great when a hook exists for the thing you want to do, but when you try to do more complicated things, the internals can get pretty tricky. I'm not familiar with the `TreeNodeChoiceField` so can't offer any tips.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to overrrides thos fields : using `deepcopy` in the get_form() method to copy the form class, and then update the fields with `base_field`:

```
class MyAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = MyForm  # class !
    def get_form(self, ...):
        self.form = deepcopy(self.form)
        form = super(MyAdmin, self).get_form(...)
        if 'foo' in form.base_fields:
            form.base_fields['foo'].queryset = my_reduced_queryset
            form.base_fields['foo'].widget = my_pretty_widget
        ...
        return form
```

Thanks for your help !